# Oracle UTL_STMP - no content

Tags: oracle, email, smtp

I send emails over the Oracle database via UTL_SMTP. This are daily emails which are sent automatically.

But on some days there is no content in the email and a blank mail is sent.

This is my code:

```
c := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION(sMailserver);
UTL_SMTP.HELO(c, sMailserver);
UTL_SMTP.MAIL(c, sFrom);
UTL_SMTP.RCPT(c, sRecipients);
UTL_SMTP.OPEN_DATA(c);

UTL_SMTP.write_data(c, 'To: ' || sRecipients || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(c, 'From: ' || sFrom || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(c, 'Subject: ' || REPLACE(sDescr, '[DATE]',TO_CHAR(sDATE,'DD.MM.YYYY')) || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(c, 'Content-Type: text/html;' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

-- Write data      
UTL_SMTP.write_data(c, sData);

UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(c);
UTL_SMTP.QUIT(c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to put a extra line between header-data and body-data:

```
UTL_SMTP.write_data(c, 'Content-Type: text/html;' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

-- Extra line between header and body
UTL_SMTP.write_data(c, UTL_TCP.crlf); 

-- Write data
UTL_SMTP.write_data(c, sData);
```